# Suppose that $p$ and $q$ are primes, with $p<q$. If $n\equiv 1$ (mod $q)\ $ and $n\mid pq$, prove that $n=1$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

My professor asked us to prove this on the group theory class (we're now learning what Sylow theorems are). I found this question a little strange, because this seems to be a question from number theory or another field. Surely I'm missimg something. This is the lemma we've been asked to prove:

> Suppose that $p$ and $q$ are primes, with $p<q$. If $n\equiv 1$ (mod $q)\ $ and $n\mid pq$, prove that $n=1$.

Someone could give me any hint? It has to be something with group theory?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $n \mid pq$, and $p$ and $q$ are primes, there are only four options: $n = 1$, $n = p$, $n = q$ or $n = pq$ (these four are the only positive numbers that divide $pq$). Now, because $n \equiv 1 \pmod q$, we cannot have $n = q$ or $n = pq$.

To rule out $n = p$, note that since $p < q$, it is clear that $p \not\equiv 1 \pmod q$. Therefore $n = 1$ is the only option left.

Comment: Is that easy? The question has $4$ points, and it's the first, so maybe it's only a little exercise that has nothing to go with groups. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

If $n \mid pq$ $\implies$ $n \mid p$  , $ $ $n \mid q$ or $n=pq$  but$ $ n$\equiv$ $1 mod $ $q$

So we get $n \mid p$ $\implies$ $n=1$ or $ $ $n=p$

If $n=p$ since $ $p$\equiv$ $1 mod $ $q$  but $p<q$ so this is a contradiction